# Dealing with private setters and id in create update scenario

Tags: c#, .net, oop

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Family : Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    
    public Family(string fname, string lname)
    {
        FirstName = fname;
        LastName = lname;
    }
}
```

The question is how do I deal with Id property here for creating and update.
Do I need to have one more constructor with id property in the constructor for creating action?

```
// create
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var new = new Family(id, "John", "Doe");

// update
 var dbData = _context.Families.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);
 var updated = new Family(dbData.FirstName, db.Data.LastName);
```

Is this recommended approach with private setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Entity` is abstract and you know that you want `Id` to be set through the constructor, and your object to be immutable you can do it through in inheritance.

Any derived type will be forced to call the base constructor to set `Id`.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public Entity(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id == Guid.Empty ? Guid.NewGuid() : id;
    }
}

public class Family : Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public Family(string fname, string lname, Guid id = default) : base(id)
    {
        FirstName = fname;
        LastName = lname;
    }
}
```